# Passing variable to javascript (chartist) with flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, chartist.js

I have the following:

views.py:

```
   return render_template('test.html',
                           title='Home',
                           labels = output_labels)
```

test.html:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/demo.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var labelsx = {{ labels|tojson }};
 </script>
```

demo.js:

```
Chartist.Pie('#chartPreferences', {
  labels: ['{{labelsx}}'],
  series: [62, 32, 6]
});
```

It looks like that demo.js is not recognizing the labelsx variable at all (tried without brackets as well). The labelsx variable before "tojson" is a list:

```
print type(output_labels)
print output_labels

<type 'list'>
[u'string1', u'string2', u'string3']
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:** In my opinion it is different to [Passing variables from flask to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259740/passing-variables-from-flask-to-javascript) since I had suggested code already in place and as per accecpted answer here, the problem was in the order of defining the variable used by .js later on - which is not mentioned in that older question.
Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variables from flask to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259740/passing-variables-from-flask-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to move your definition of `labelsx` to before you load the JavaScript that uses it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var labelsx = {{ labels|tojson }};
</script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/demo.js') }}"></script>
```

And then in `demo.js`, you just need to use the variable directly. It seems like you're treating it like a server-side variable in a template, but your JavaScript is being processed as a template at all:

```
Chartist.Pie('#chartPreferences', {
  labels: labelsx,
  series: [62, 32, 6]
});
```

**UPDATE**

I would personally prefer to expose a function from `demo.js` and then call it from your HTML. This avoids creating the global variable `labelsx`. So, `demo.js`:

```
function drawChart(labels) {
  Chartist.Pie('#chartsPreferences', {
    labels: labels,
    series: [62, 32, 6],
  });
}
```

And `test.html`:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename=js/demo.js') }}"></script>
<script>
  drawChart({{ labels|tojson }});
</script>
```

Comment: Great, it turned out that I just had to define `labelsx` before calling `demo.js`. Suggestion regarding global variable is appreciated as well! Thanks.