# Read a variable name in Javascript from Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am passing variable from Flask to JavaScript using the method render_template.

I followed this post: [Passing variables from flask to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259740/passing-variables-from-flask-to-javascript), but it is not working for me

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/debug')
def index_debug():
    return render_template('index.html', debug=True)
```

I would like to read it from a JavaScript file. I tried using this method:

this is my html file:

```
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var debugMode = {{ debug }};
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/static/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

But when i try accessing this variable in my index.js. the variable debugMode  is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<head> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.debugMode = {{ debug }};
 </script>
 <script src="/static/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

If you want to read a **variable** from HTML in JS you ought to declare this var in **window** scope and read in JS file like this.

```
const myNewVar = window.debugMode
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But on my JS file, I am trying to read it :
let debugMode= window.debugMode
But window.debugMode is undefined

Comment: When you console.log window.debugMode in Chrome console, it's also undefined?

Comment: Yes. I tired to print it also in the console

Comment: Did you also check the page source? To be sure that window.debug  has any value.

Comment: Yes.
This is the header file in the HTML:
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  window.debugMode = True;
 </script>
 <script src="/static/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/static/index.js"></script>
    
</head>
(I can't put code or image in the comment)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> window.debugMode = True; </script>. 
I found the problem **True** should be  **true**.