# HTML "variable" to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I can't comeup the terminology: what is the "answer" that the server sends to Get method? It builds the HTML document, but how it's called? Answer document?

I'm trying to find how i can get the html value (rname in this situation) to javascript. My server makes this html "welcome ... " text, but now i would need to reuse that name in javascript (at the same page).

```
<h1> Welcome {{rname}} </h1>
```

How i can assign rname to javascript variable?

I found this solution, but it seems way over complicated to just read one "variable"
[Passing variables from Flask to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259740/passing-variables-from-flask-to-javascript/37260465)

Answer (score 1):

somewhere in your html template you can assign that value to a global js variable:

```
<h1> Welcome {{rname}} </h1>
<script>
  var username = {{rname}};
</script>
```

EDIT:
to avoid conflicts, since this is a global variable, you might want to give it a more unique name like `global_username`

Answer (score 1):

It is called response and you could get variables from response by res.something. But you need to specify which technology you use for communicating with your server.