# How to pass variables from Flask to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm using Flask to develop a python application.
I did a locale management and it's ok everywhere in the application but i gave a issue with external JS.

I want to have a template hml with a link inside like \<script src="/static/js/user/bundle.js"\>\</script\> and in this one use the variable like {{translate_1}}. It's ok when i put variables in JS directly into the template but i want to have something clean. Someone did that ? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variables from Flask to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259740/passing-variables-from-flask-to-javascript)

Comment: How do you parse data from your flask application to your JavaScript/HTML frontend? Most of the time you will return `JSON` from your backend and then update the frontend variables based on what is returned from the backend. But please give more infomation in your question.